# Azure service bus queue partitioning based on Customer ID

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I am trying to create multiple partitions based on Customer ID parameter on my Json property . How can I do this ?

Comment: I have a hunch I know the reason you're asking for this but want to clarify prior to posting how to shoot yourself in the foot. What are you trying to accomplish with the partition key set to the customer ID?

Comment: Hi, any update? If my answer answered your question, can you [mark it as the answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2eE3.jpg) to end this question? Thanks.:)

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specific the language you are using, so I assume you are using java.

First of all, create a service bus queue on azure.

And use below dependencies:(I am based on Maven.)

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
     <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
      <artifactId>azure-messaging-servicebus</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
     <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
     <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

This is the code:

```
package bowmantest;
import com.azure.messaging.servicebus.*;
import com.azure.messaging.servicebus.models.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

import javax.json.JsonObject;
import javax.json.Json;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        
        //Create a json and get the value.
        JsonObject testjson = Json.createObjectBuilder()
        .add("CustomID", "bowmantestPK").build();
        //String str = testjson.get("CustomID").toString();
        String str = testjson.getString("CustomID");

        String connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://bowman1012.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=X/NHgQ4AQxul6YlMsUofD+JNE20Tovnzx3g2gDt8qyY=";
        String queueName = "testbowman";
        
        // create a Service Bus Sender client for the queue 
        ServiceBusSenderClient senderClient = new ServiceBusClientBuilder()
        .connectionString(connectionString)
        .sender()
        .queueName(queueName)
        .buildClient();


        ServiceBusMessage servicebusmessage = new ServiceBusMessage("Hello, World!");
        servicebusmessage.setPartitionKey(str);

        // send one message to the queue
        senderClient.sendMessage(servicebusmessage);
        System.out.println("Sent a single message to the queue: " + queueName);   
    }
}
```

(Above is Console app, function is similar.)